# Can a healing belt be used to heal oneself or only others?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I am having some trouble determining if a *healing belt* from the *Magic Item Compendium* (p.110) can be used to heal oneself as well as others or if it is only able to be used to heal others.

Based on the fact that it seems to indicate it works as a spell with a range of "touch" I am thinking it cannot be used to heal oneself.

The item description reads as follows:

> Activation: — and standard (command)
>
> This broad leather belt is studded with three moonstones.  While wearing a healing belt, you gain a +2 competence bonus on Heal checks. This is a continuous effect and requires no activation.  In addition, the belt has 3 charges, which are renewed each day at dawn. Spending 1 or more charges allows you to **channel positive energy and heal damage with a touch**. **(You can also use this ability to harm undead, dealing them an equivalent amount of damage instead.)**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Touch effects can be used on yourself at any time. This is true for any and all touch effects, and spending a charge of a *healing belt* is no exception.

Per [touch spells in combat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#touchSpellsinCombat):

> You can automatically touch one friend or use the spell on yourself, but to touch an opponent, you must succeed on an attack roll.

So the *healing belt* can be used on yourself, or used on a friend you can touch, but to attack an (undead, presumably) enemy with it, you have to make a touch attack.